# Regular Expression in Objective-C for finding HTML anchor list

Tags: html, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm beginning to develop in Objective-C, and I'm have a problem finding the correct regular expression to list the anchor in an HTML document.

Example: I have this HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="class1" href="/document1.html"></li>
    <li><a class="class1" href="/document2.html"></li>
    <li><a class="class1" href="/document3.html"></li>
</ul>
```

I want get a NSArray with a result like this:

```
/document1.html
/document2.html
/document3.html
```

How can I make a good regular expression for this?

Comment: [You don't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1705725)

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complicated to do this properly in regex, with all of the generalities that HTML permits. It's better to use a HTML parser, such as Hpple. See Ray Wenderlich's [How to Parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios).

But, if you're interested in just some special cases (e.g. the `href` always in double quotes), you can do something like:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex;
regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<a\\s[^>]*(?<=\\s)href\\s*=\\s*\"(.*?)\".*?>"
                                                  options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                    error:&error];
```

There are numerous limitations here, but maybe it's a starting point. For something more general, you really should pursue a HTML parser, not regex.